# NUnit and TestCaseAttribute, cross-join of parameters possible?

Tags: c#, nunit, testcaseattribute

I have a unit-test that tests a variety of cases, like this:

```
public void Test1(Int32 a, Int32 b, Int32 c)
```

Let's say I want to create test-code without a loop, so I want to use TestCase to specify parameters like this:

```
[TestCase(1, 1, 1)]
public void Test1(Int32 a, Int32 b, Int32 c)
```

Is it possible for me with this attribute to say this:

- For the first parameter, here's a set of values
- For the second parameter, here's a set of values
- For the third parameter, here's a set of values
- **Now, test all combinations of the above**

Ie. something like this:

```
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 })]
public void Test1(Int32 a, Int32 b, Int32 c)
```

Doesn't seem like it, but perhaps I'm overlooking something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

NUnit provides the [Values](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=values&r=2.5.2) attribute which can be used together with [Combinatorial](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=combinatorial&r=2.5.2) attribute to achieve this:

```
[Test, Combinatorial]
public void Test1( 
    [Values(1,2,3,4)] Int32 a, 
    [Values(1,2,3,4)] Int32 b, 
    [Values(1,2,3,4)] Int32 c
)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: That worked, and Combinatorial is apparently the default as well, intellisense doc said that, and I tried without that particular attribute and it worked exactly like you said it would. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen In addition to the `Values` attribute, the [`Range` attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=range&r=2.5) can also be used in the same manner. Instead of explicitly listing all of the values, they can be specified as a range. So, in your example, instead of `[Values(1,2,3,4)]`, you can substitute with `[Range(1,4,1)]`.